# Animated overlap view with itself

Tags: android, animation, view

I have listview. When tap on it, I want to **overlap** it with another data by using translate animation. But if I replace adapter in `onAnimationStart()`, data from below will disappear, which is unacceptable. 
So is there a way to do this without using 2 listview components?

Comment: You could merge new data with existing data in the adapter..